# Docker doesn't start MONGODB, and IPAddress doesn't appear, when started with other services

Tags: ssh, mongodb, rabbitmq, docker

I have been trying to build an OS image from Fedora unsuccessfully to start the following:

1. Systemd
2. SSHD
3. RabbitMQ
4. MongoDB

I can get the first 3 (Systemd, SSHD and RabbitMQ-Server) to work. I can also get MongoDB to work within the container. However, I cannot get MongoDB to work along with other 3 services.

In addition, IP address doesn't show up when I try to "dockerize" MongoDB.

Am I missing something in the Dockerfile?

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora:20
MAINTAINER “Ashfaque” <ashfaque@email.com>
ENV container docker
RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install systemd; yum clean all; \
(cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

# Dockerizing SSH - is working
RUN yum -y install openssh-server
RUN yum -y install openssh-clients
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN systemctl enable sshd.service
RUN echo 'root:mypassword' |chpasswd
EXPOSE 22

# Dockerizing RabbitMQ - is working
RUN yum -y install rabbitmq-server
EXPOSE 5672 15672
RUN systemctl enable rabbitmq-server

# Dockerizing MongoDB - is NOT WORKING
RUN yum -y install mongodb-server
RUN yum -y install boost
RUN yum -y install scons
# Create the MongoDB data directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/db /var/log/mongodb /var/run/mongodb
RUN sed -i 's/dbpath =\/var\/lib\/mongodb/dbpath =\/data\/db/' /etc/mongodb.conf
# Expose port 27017 from the container to the host
EXPOSE 27017
# Set usr/bin/mongod as the dockerized entry-point application
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
#CMD ["--port", "27017", "--dbpath", "/data/db", "--smallfiles", "--fork", "--syslog"]
#RUN /usr/bin/mongod --smallfiles --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --fork --syslog

VOLUME ["/sys/fs/cgroup", "/data/db", "/var/log/mongodb", "/usr/bin"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Docker Commands used to build are:

(1) docker build -t rabbitmq_mongo_heisenbug .

(2) docker run --privileged -d -e 'container=docker' -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro  -p 29022:22  -p 29672:15672 -p 29017:27017 rabbitmq_mongo_heisenbug

or..
(3) docker run --privileged -ti -e 'container=docker' -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro  -p 29022:22  -p 29672:15672 -p 29017:27017 rabbitmq_mongo_heisenbug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Ref: [Docker doesn't start MONGODB, and IPAddress doesn't appear, when started with other services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481107/docker-doesnt-start-mongodb-and-ipaddress-doesnt-appear-when-started-with-ot)